# Scrapy - switch from selenium/browser back to default mechanism in single spider

Tags: python, ajax, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I've encountered page with Ajax hidden elements, which I need to crawl. I've found this neat tutorial which shows how to do this with Selenium, in case when there is no additional calls to the server (this is the case for me as well).

http://www.6020peaks.com/2014/12/how-to-scrape-hidden-web-data-with-python/

However this and other sources mention a performance cost of using Selenium for this purpose. In this example the driver is initiated in the constructor, so I'm assuming all requests for the spider will go via Firefox then?

I just have a small portion of calls with Ajax involved, the rest is standard Scrapy crawling. Is it feasible to switch from Selenium/Browser in a single spider after part of the tasks were completed, back to the default Scrapy mechanism? If so how should I try to do this?

```
def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

def parse(self, response):
    items = []
    self.driver.get(response.url)
```

**Edit**

What I'm after is getting the Ajax based menu scraped from a single site, just the URLs. Then I want to pass this list to as start_urls to the main spider.

Comment: Have you tried the ScrapyJS middleware?

Comment: No, I'm looking at this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not break standard scrapy behaviour, try switch to standard way like this

```
def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

def parse(self, response):
    items = []
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    # get hidden menu urls
    yield scrapy.Request(hidden_menu_url, callback=self.parse_original_scrapy)

 def parse_original_scrapy(self, response):
    pass
```

You can to try my framework - [Pomp](https://bitbucket.org/estin/pomp) instead of scrapy.

Start with [phantomjs example](https://bitbucket.org/estin/pomp/src/a8f13e7c9d5f950223b36f1ac96258c20359b43c/examples/e05_phantomjs.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) and implement yours own `Downloader` that would be dispatch request to webdriver or fetch it by plain http request. It is not so easy to do, but much better then use webdriver inside parse method of scrapy spider.

Sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do this, as Scrapy crawls the request you send, plain text, without javascript rendering, something like `curl` if you've tried it.

The process of passing from Selenium to only Scrapy is possible by working every single (or just the necessary) request, you can use chrome dev tools or firebug to check which requests are being done for every call inside a browser, and then check the information you want and which requests are the necessary to get them.

Comment: What about sending more requests in one spider - part selenium based and once this is done, repeat the request, would this be doable?

Comment: totally, it is python so you can do whatever you want inside the callback methods. Another thing to take into account, is that you can use [`splash`](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) which renders javascript as a service, and plays really well with scrapy.

Comment: Hi eLRuLL, could you see my edit and give me a suggestion? I think I'm confused how to combine 2 scrapers into a single project? I don't want to fire up the spider two times, just have all in one executable solution.

Comment: maybe you haven't seen the `start_requests` method, you can load everything you want with selenium and then create the requests you want. `def start_requests(self)` is the method that gets the `start_urls` by default, but you can override it to start your spider however you want.